# Why can't I assign the value returned by grep to a variable?

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I have tried:

```
TOTAL_MEM= $(grep MemTotal /proc/meminfo | awk '{print $2}')
TOTAL_MEM= 'grep MemTotal /proc/meminfo | awk '{print $2}''
TOTAL_MEM= grep MemTotal /proc/meminfo | awk '{print $2}'
```

and every time I call:

```
echo "Total memory available: " $TOTAL_MEM
```

It just returns blank.. What did I miss?

Comment: You didn't miss anything. You added an extra space (after the `=`). Remove it. The first attempt was correct other than that.

Comment: `mem=$(awk '/MemTotal/ {print $2}' /proc/meminfo)` is better

Answer (score 2):

Cred to Anubhava for posting this first, but here is a good way to do it:

```
TOTAL_MEM=$(awk '/MemTotal/ {print $2}' /proc/meminfo)
```

---

Does not work since there are space after `=`

```
TOTAL_MEM= $(grep MemTotal /proc/meminfo | awk '{print $2}')
```

---

Does not work since there are space after `=` and wrong quoting.  Use parentheses or backtics.  (Best to use parentheses)

```
TOTAL_MEM= 'grep MemTotal /proc/meminfo | awk '{print $2}''
```

---

Does not work since there are space after `=` and missing quoting.

```
TOTAL_MEM= grep MemTotal /proc/meminfo | awk '{print $2}'
```